# Help me figure out this 12AX7 Tube Preamp mess

Tags: amplifier, vacuum-tube

A few years ago I built a Tube guitar amp / pedal / preamp with a 12ax7 tube (and some other pin compatible tubes). I don't remember what schematic I used to make it and I wasn't skilled with electronics then but surprisingly sound *does* come out of it, and I really like the distortion when the tube is overdriven.

[image: Circuit Diagram]
It looks like I've made some whack decisions when building it:

1. I have no idea how I arrived at the resistor values, as well as their wattage
2. The capacitors don't look like they are the right type or values
3. The heater connections look weird, whats with the grounded middle?
4. The pots look like they are 1M each, Is that sane?
5. The amp is really quiet, even turning all pots to maximum with line level input. It distorts slightly, but I was expecting it to be massively distorted (in a good way) when turned up to the max.
6. Whats with the 100uF *Electrolytic* caps on the cathodes of the triode?
7. Where should the ground be connected in this setup. I'm getting intermittent hum when I connect a guitar to the input, and speakers/amp to the output, but fine if I play music to it from my phone
8. Why the two resistors around the output potentiometer (see Update below)

I would love for someone who is familiar with tube amplifiers to look this over and help me work out right values and parts.

Here is an [album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjDzP.jpg) with couple of pictures of the insides, Its not pretty.

### Update:

Crud, I forgot about the two resistors across the output potentiometer. From the 2nd picture from the bottom of that album, the resistor across output and ground is 100k and one across capacitor and output is 1M

Comment: You might want to measure some voltages and mark them on your schematic. The B+, cathode voltages, grid voltages, filament voltages (use DC range), and plate voltages. **9 voltages** total.

Comment: Will do. Should these be measured without an input signal, and without output load? (in my case load is a set of powered PC speakers)

Comment: Start with with no input.

Comment: B+ is 135V, U1 cathode is at 1.2v U2 cathode at 0.7v. Both grids are at 0v. heater is a bit weird. One side is 4.5v, other is 4.1v, that is, pin 4 is 8v above pin 5, and pin 9 is somewhere in the middle of that. I don't think this is ideal, as the heater should be run at 12v (or 6 if they are in parallel)

Comment: I have a pretty crappy meter, these readings are maybe 10s of mV off

Comment: That's okay. What about the plate voltages?

Comment: The plate voltages are 8.1v for U1, and 4.5v for U2

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem right. I think my meter's impedance (its an analog, deflection needle type) is messing with the measurements, on a higher scale I measure 200v for B+ and plate voltages of 170v for U1 and 100v for U2 =/

Comment: The cathode voltages seem accurate though.

Comment: You're obviously loading the plate voltages excessively, but we can tell what the plate voltages are from the cathode voltages.

Comment: Having a go with some music (line level) playing through it. When i touch my meter to the plate, the sound dies. However, using a higher scale it hardly changes. With music playing everything is the same really, U1 plate +180v, U2 plate +65v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommended configurations for the 12AX7 are below:

[image: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/121279/GEC/12AX7/+02Q_8AVEDwa8AEbw+/datasheet.pdf]

Since the cathode resistor is bypassed for audio frequencies by the 100uF capacitors, gain will be set by the transconductance of the tube under the operating conditions, as shown in the above diagram. Lowering the plate resistance, especially on V2, will allow you drive a lower input impedance input.

Below is your original circuit with your voltage measurements and calculated plate voltages shown.

[image]

Comment: I found this diagram earlier too, I found it hard to read, however, because I have two stages, and the values don't quite make sense. My Rks are 330k and 380k, should they be 0, or 1-4k ?

Comment: what about the two C's too. Are the ones i'm using now ok? I highly doubt they are rated for 100-200v. They are just normal caps I use for microchips and that

Comment: Your Rks are 15K and 4.7K which means the tubes are running at much lower current than optimal. It's possible your B+ supply is so weak that the optimal values won't work for you.

Comment: The plate coupling capacitor voltage rating should be something like 200V. The input coupling cap and the cathode caps can be low voltage (10V or 25V).

Comment: Ah, i misread it again! I will try lowering the Rk values and see how it sounds

Comment: Try lowering the plate resistances in proportion.

Comment: Thank you for annotating my diagram, thats really helpful. I'm going to have to desolder the mess as it is now to try some different values. I will fix the heater supply while I'm at it too. I think i'll ground one side and just send 10v across the whole heater with a 50R resistor, that should be enough current.